# How images adjust their size in collection view cell in landscape or portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have problem regarding **scrolling images in collection view** . i want that only 1 image will show while rotating the phone but there are 2 to 3 images shown in portrait as well as landscape mode . what is the proper solution regarding this problem?

Comment: Please read it once https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show some code/graphics.

Comment: You'll have to work with the layout of the collection view. You'll have to create custom rotation animation in layout.

Comment: i am done with portrait and landscape mode but now the biggest problem is this when i start scrolling it , 2 images are shown of half half size , i want that only 1 image will be there

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
            {
               return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 10 , height: collectionView.frame.height )
                
            }

Comment: try this, @simran                                                                                                             func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10 , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height ) }